# SQL Server : primary key date plus auto increment start from 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure that will create a table every month where the primary key starts with a letter which will identify where it came from, then current date followed by an auto increment starting from 1000 and will reset every new month/table. I already did the current date thing but I am having a hard time doing the increment starting from 1000.

```
IF @product = apple 
  BEGIN 
      print A
  END 
ELSE IF @product = banana
  BEGIN 
      print B
  END 
ELSE IF @product = carrot
  BEGIN 
      print C
  END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    print NONE
    END

SELECT
    @refnum = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102), '.', '') AS [MMDDYYYY])

PRINT @refnum

INSERT INTO '+@sourceTable+' (refno)
    SELECT ('+@product+''+@refnum+')
```

I just add this part where my date is being inserted into the table, do you have any idea how can I make it like this "A03162016-1001", "B03162016-1002", "B03162016-1003", "03162016-1004". . . . .

And is it possible to create a SP where I can make a auto increment that starts from 1000? I saw the other post asking for the same procedure but it doesn't work in SQL Server.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to create a multitude of tables for the same objects.  It is better to store more rows in a single table.

Comment: I see, so I will just split that into 3 rows then, thanks for that advise!

Comment: It is equally bad to try to create your own PK values.

Comment: why is it bad to create own PK values ?

Comment: So my problem now is how to have a auto increment that starts from 1000.

Comment: @VinceOsana: add this to your table `SomeID INT IDENTITY(1000, 1)` - the first number in the `IDENTITY` specification is the **start value** (and the second is the increment)

Comment: So will that work if I do it like this? `set @sql = '
 CREATE TABLE '+@Table+'
 (
  
  [refID] INT IDENTITY(1000, 1)

 )
 '    
 print @sql
 exec (@sql)`

Comment: Better leave the primary key as a simple identity column, and create a computed column that will hold the `A03162016-1000` - `A03162016-9999` values.